# sql write 5 columns into just 2 columns

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

i have a sql view that has 5 columns. I want that data written to a table but with only 2 columns,

view

```
id 
car1
car2
car3
car4
```

table

```
id
cars
```

---

```
INSERT INTO table 
SELECT * from view
```

Comment: Have you tried to concat values? like this: car1||car2||...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert cars (id, car)
select id, cars
from view
unpivot
(cars for car in (car1, car2,car3, car4)) as u
```

Answer (score 2):

Brute force and ignorance (but reliable):

```
INSERT INTO table
   SELECT id, car1 FROM view WHERE car1 IS NOT NULL
   UNION
   SELECT id, car2 FROM view WHERE car2 IS NOT NULL
   UNION
   SELECT id, car3 FROM view WHERE car3 IS NOT NULL
   UNION
   SELECT id, car4 FROM view WHERE car4 IS NOT NULL
```

The UNION has the merit of eliminating any duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

`INSERT INTO table SELECT ID, Car1 + ',' + Car2 + ',' +  Car3 + ',' + Car4 as Cars from view`